# Are welcome messages in answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

I saw [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/371960/144700) and am not sure if the “Welcome to SuperUser.” at the beginning should be removed. It seems out of place to me…and aren't new users shown or emailed a welcome page or something anyway?

**EDIT:** Whoops, that answer is six months old. Didn't see that at first…I guess it shouldn't be edited because of that? I'm leaving this question up for future reference, though…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't matter when it was posted. That cruft is ripe for editing out.

Feel free to edit (or suggest an edit) that removes such flower arrangements. But don't forget to also fix up anything else in the post that may need it, from typos and grammar to adding paragraphs to wall of text bleakers.

Comment: Right—I actually clicked the /edit/ link and removed the welcome, then went through and looked for spelling and grammar mistakes (just read up on editing…), but I didn't see any. I thought I'd check to see if in-post welcomes were okay before I committed the edit, though.

Comment: If you can't find anything else to fix, it's fine to continue with the excising